# Position icon next to text

Tags: html, css, angular, mat-icon

I have created a div which shows an icon and text but I need to get the icon next to the text instead of above it. Currently looks like this:

[image]

And I need the icon to be next to the text like this (the icon needs to be displayed to the left of the text without moving the text so the header still aligns with the phone number):

[image]

Code:

```
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center">
            <div>
                <mat-icon svgIcon="phone-outline"> </mat-icon>
                <h3>Customer Support</h3>
                <label>123456</label>
            </div>
         <div>
            <mat-icon svgIcon="email-outline"> </mat-icon>
            <h3>Email</h3>
            <label>test@email.com</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <mat-icon svgIcon="map-marker-outline"> </mat-icon>
            <h3>Address</h3>
            <label>address line 1</label>
        </div>
   </div>
```

I have three divs and using fxLayoutAlign aligns them next to each other accoss the page but if I put the icon into a seperate div the fxLayoutAlign moves it too far across the page. Is there a better way to align the divs?

Tried so far:

1. Tried putting the icon on the same line as the text but that puts the icon too close to the text:
   `<h3><mat-icon svgIcon="phone-outline"> </mat-icon> Customer Support</h3>`

[image]

I need to have space between the icon and text and align it with the text.

2. Using CSS to try align still causes the icon to be too close to the text (and not aligned correctly):
   `.align-items { display: flex; justify-content: space-between; } .align-content { display: flex; align-items: center; }`

[image]

Moving the icon in CSS using margins looks like its working but it has now moved the second line with the phone number:

[image]

The phone number should be directly under the header text (like in first screenshot above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another approach with pure css.

css

```
.align-items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.align-content {
  display: flex;
}

mat-icon {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.align-text-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

h3 {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

html

```
<div class="align-items ">
    <div class="align-text-item">
        <div class="align-content">
            <mat-icon svgIcon="thumbs-up" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example thumbs up SVG icon"></mat-icon>
            <div>
                <h3>Customer Support</h3>
                123456
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="align-text-item">
        <div class="align-content">
            <mat-icon svgIcon="thumbs-up" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example thumbs up SVG icon"></mat-icon>
            <div>
                <h3>Email</h3>
                123456
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="align-text-item">
        <div class="align-content">
            <mat-icon svgIcon="thumbs-up" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example thumbs up SVG icon"></mat-icon>
            <div>
                <h3>Address</h3>
                123456
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please see edited question of how using this CSS looks. Unfortuately the icon is too close to the text and does not align with the text

Comment: I tested with another icon and it is aligned with text. Can you share a stackblitz?

Comment: Using margins has worked to move the icon but now the phone number under the header text has moved. I edited my question to include screenshot of what it looks like now

Comment: Check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gitauf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) if its ok, to update my answer

Comment: Yes the stackblitz is correct for showing the icons so I marked this as accepted for the answer. But do you know how to align the text 123456 with the headers? So 123456 should be align under customer support, email and address

Comment: I updated my answer, so now you have what you asked in the last comment.Try to play with [flex propery](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp) if you want to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class for the divs wrapping the icon and heading. No fxLayout is needed

```
.align-icon{
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: I was using fxLayout so the 3 divs were spaced out (first div on left, second in middle, and third on the right). If I remove fxLayout the divs now go under each other. And there is no space between the icon and text using this class

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `matPrefix` and `matSuffix`

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <mat-icon matPrefix>mode_edit</mat-icon>
    <mat-label>EXAMPLE</mat-label>
    <mat-icon matSuffix>mode_edit</mat-icon>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: I cannot use mat-form-field because I am just using h3 and label tags. Using this code causes the error - Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl

Answer (score -2):

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center">
            <div>               
                <h3>Customer Support<mat-icon svgIcon="phone-outline"> </mat-icon></h3>
            </div>
         <div>
            <mat-icon svgIcon="email-outline"> </mat-icon>
            <h3>Email</h3>
        </div>enter code here
        <div>
            <mat-icon svgIcon="map-marker-outline"> </mat-icon>
            <h3>Address</h3>
        </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: This puts the icon too close to the text. I need space between the icon and text. Please see edited question - I have included a screenshot of what the icon looks like doing this